# Does a programming language with ML-style modules need packages?

Tags: language-design, code-reuse, language-features, packages, modules

This is a clarification of [a closed question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/439852/398052). I've limited the scope as requested.

First, a few definitions, following e.g. [A modular module system](https://xavierleroy.org/publi/modular-modules-jfp.pdf). Consider any programming language with a selected subtheory of its [native type theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.04672). Let a **signature** be two collections of named types, allowing for polymorphism; the first collection is the **imports** (also called the **givens**) and the second collection is the **exports** (also confusingly called the **module type**.) A **ML-style module** is a collection of named sentences in the language which can be judged to have the same types as the exports when in the context of values with the same types as the imports. A **ML-style functor** is an ML-style module whose imports include module types; the imports and exports of one module are among the imports to another module.

Given all of this, we'll say that a language **admits ML-style modules** when we can choose a type theory such that its ML-style modules and ML-style functors form a category, we can embed that category in the language's original syntax, and:

- there is an initial object (an empty signature)
- there are subobjects (the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) always holds)

Finally, we'll say that an ML-style package is a named collection of ML-style modules. Packages do not need to obey any compositional rules; they do not have type signatures.

For example, most flavors of ML admit ML-style modules, including [SML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML), [OCaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml), and [ATS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATS_(programming_language)). [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell) can do it with Backpack, and [Racket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_(programming_language)) can do it with units. Additionally, languages like ECMAScript and Java can be restricted to admit ML-style modules using their existing module systems.

Suppose that a programming language admits ML-style modules, but its ecosystem does not have ML-style packages. Which software engineering tasks -- if any -- are expensive or impossible without packages?

Comment: Ideally you should modify the original question, and request re-opening it.

Comment: I see ML and SML all over this question. Can you define those abbreviations? I keep thinking ML = Machine Learning.

Comment: This question is confusing. Are you asking what things are hard because a language supports module exports, like ECMA Script, but pretend that NPM packages don't use exports?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: [ML](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) is one of the most important and influential programming languages. Its name is just ML. It is not an abbreviation. Every programming language with generics is influenced by ML. ML is considered to have one of the most powerful and featureful, yet type-safe and sound module systems, so every programming language with a module system is either influenced by ML or is at least measured against ML. Every functional language since the 1970s is influenced by ML. So are C++, Java, Scala, Rust, TypeScript, Erlang, and more.

Comment: SML technically stands for *Standard ML*, but nobody calls it that. It is always just called SML. In both cases, I would assume someone answering a question about programming language design, specifically about module systems, would be familiar with those two programming languages and needs no definition.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Added bluelinks. Jörg's summary of ML is excellent. For ECMAScript, I'm asking you to imagine that modules are strictly statically typed, as if we were using TypeScript. Note that TS cannot typecheck packages before downloading them, extracting the individual modules, and placing all of the modules in a common setting; modules must typecheck, but packages might not.

Comment: @l0b0: Sorry, overlooked you earlier. The initial question was like the final paragraph; it was roughly, "Suppose that a programming language has modules but not packages. Which software engineering tasks are impossible without packages?" Short, sweet, and apparently not specific enough.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Sorry, missed your second comment! TBH I think the answer is a flat "no"; packages are about ego, collaboration, incorrect behaviors, corporate needs, and a great many things which aren't related to well-typed programs. Your prior answer was focused on licensing and availability of packages, but I want to focus on the idea that modules are viable units of distribution on their own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modules and packages solve different problems, though they certainly overlap, and can be made nearly synonymous.

1. Packages provide a critical source of **namespacing**. Modules aren't guaranteed unique names, and even with the right combination of imports and exports, at some point you'd need disambiguation tools if you are drawing from two modules with the same name. If module names are made universally unique, you can begin to blur these two concepts.
2. Packages provide control of **versioning**. This becomes especially critical when multiple modules each depend on different versions of the same module (e.g. module A depends on C-0.8, B on C-1.2).  A language's package management system must disambiguate and link modules to their intended targets. If modules carry optional version information in their names, you can begin to blur these two concepts.
3. Packages provide control of **sourcing**. The location and method of requisition of a package is all tied up at the package level: do you pull it from GitHub? From a public package repository? From your company's private artifact store? This part of the problem could theoretically be dealt with at the module level, but it's increasingly noisy to do so. However, if there are tools to abstract away package requisition, you can indeed begin to blur these two concepts.

The primary place I've seen this expressed at the moment is in the [Unison language](https://www.unison-lang.org/) - it makes a number of very unusual tradeoffs to get there, but in return you get *unique global identifiers for code objects*. I'm not sure if it can fully replicate ML modules, but it does solve the 'namespacing' and 'versioning' problems quite compactly. A similar concept may serve well in accomplishing your intended aims.

---

Comment: You may be interested in my [Cammy](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cammy) language. I was inspired somewhat by Unison and Dark. Cammy doesn't admit ML-style modules, due to a lack of syntax; Unison is in a similar spot. Nonetheless, indeed Cammy doesn't have packages, and I wanted to know what I'm missing as a result.